# Strange Unit Test Run Time Differences

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I have unit test methods calling exactly same thing :

```
void Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
}
```

One of them is always run in different duration.

[image]

If I remove first one, `TestMethod3` is always different:

[image]

If I add another test methods, `TestMethod6` is always different:

[image]

There is always one method that is different from others.
What is the reason behind this strange difference?

I am currently studying on algorithms and trying to measure run times with test methods. This difference made me think whether test method run times are reliable.

Comment: That has something to do with the test runner. the tests are usually run simultaneously but the ones you see with the greater time is the one that was started first. I've noticed that for years now. if you were to run one of them on their own you will notice that its run time will be longer.

Comment: @Nkosi I think this should be an (right) answer, not a comment :)

Comment: Added as an answer. I didn't add it originally because I've never seen any official documentation. That comment was based on my experience of using VS over a decade.

Answer (score 1):

That has something to do with the test runner in visual studio. The tests are usually run simultaneously but the ones you see with the greater time is usually the one that was started first. I've noticed that in visual studio for years now. If you were to run one of them on their own you will notice that its run time will be longer than if it was run as part of a run all.

I've always assumed that it had to do with the timer being started early while the tests were still loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test performance in a simple unit test. Part of the reason is that there are many different implementations and configurations of testing frameworks, with different impacts on the performance of a test.

The most notable is whether tests run in parallel, multi-threaded, or consecutively. Obviously the first option completely invalidates any benchmarking. The second option, though, still doesn't guarantee a valid benchmarking.

This is because of other factors which are independent of the actual unit testing framework: These include

- Initial delays due to class loading and memory allocation
- Just-in-time compilation of your byte code into machine code. This is difficult to control and can happen seemingly unpredictably.
- Branch prediction, which may greatly influence your runtime behaviour, depending on the nature of the processed data and control flow
- Garbage collection

Doing even remotely valid benchmarks in Java is an art form in itself. In order to get close, you should at least ensure that

- you are running your code of interest in a single thread, with no other active threads
- don't use garbage collection (i.e. make sure that there is enough memory for the test to perform without GC, and setting the GC options of your JVM appropriately)
- have a warmup phase where you run your code in a sufficient number of iterations *before* starting to benchmark it.

This IBM article on ['Robust Java Benchmarking'](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-benchmark1/) is helpful as an introduction of the pitfalls of Java benchmarking.